# Min swaps for sorting list of consecutive integers

Tags: python, sorting, optimization

The problem:

> You are given an unordered array consisting of consecutive integers `[1, 2, 3, ..., n]` without any duplicates. You are allowed to swap any two elements. You need to find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array in ascending order.

My solution/issue:

My code does what it is supposed to; however, for large arrays it takes longer to run than allowed.

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    swaps = 0
    for num in range(1, len(arr)):
        if num != arr.index(num)+1: 
            arr[arr.index(num)] = arr[num-1]
            arr[num-1] = num
            swaps+=1
    return swaps
```

Any ideas/advice on how could I optimize this?

Comment: The minimum amount of transpositions seems like it would require expressing the permutation that you are trying to do as a product of disjoint cycles and then expressing each cycle as a product of transpositions (where a cycle of length `k` can be expressed as a product of `k-1` transpositions, but no fewer).

Comment: Seems you're asking for a solution to this [Hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-swaps-2/problem)

Comment: See [this quesion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/4096/50346) from [cstheory.se] for more information.

Comment: [Solution with Python code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/) which satisfied Hackerrank time constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `list.index` method costs *O(n)* in time complexity, calling it in a loop over the length of the list would result in *O(n ^ 2)* time complexity.

You can instead map the numbers in the list to their respective indices as a dict, so that the lookup of a number's index would cost *O(1)* on average, resulting in an overall time complexity of *O(n)* instead. Update the indices accordingly whenever a swap is performed:

```
def minimumSwaps(arr):
    index = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(arr)}
    swaps = 0
    for num in range(1, len(arr)):
        if num != index[num] + 1:
            arr[index[num]] = arr[num - 1]
            index[arr[num - 1]] = index[num]
            arr[num - 1] = num
            index[num] = arr[num - 1]
            swaps += 1
    return swaps
```

Comment: Good, the solution works in satisfying the time constraints of the [source of the posters problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-swaps-2/problem) thus my upvote.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I wasn't aware of the list.index method costing O(n). It is only recently that I am trying to pay special attention to efficiency. Thank you for your input.